# Custom Extension Method on object properties to return DefaultValue

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I want to create a custom extension that will work on the properties of an object `T`, regardless of the type of the property. I need the extension to get the value of the `DefaultValue` attribute.

Looking at the class below, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
string defaultNationality = employee.employeeNationality.GetDefaultValue();
```

Where `Employee` is defined as

```
public class Employee
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int employeeKey { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [Category("Design")]
    [Description("The name of the employee.")]
    public string employeeName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Active")]
    [Category("Settings")]
    [Description("Indicates whether the employee is in active service.")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool employeeIsActive { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nationality")]
    [Category("Settings")]
    [Description("The nationality of the employee.")]
    [DefaultValue("Dutch")]
    public string employeeNationality { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Reflection and Linq Expression. The way you want to do it will only be able to check the current value and get a default based on that. With a Linq expression you can use reflection to get the attributes. ie `employee.GetDefaultValue(x => x.employeeNationality);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use such extension method:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static K GetDefaultValue<T, K>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, K>> exp)
    {
        var info = ((MemberExpression)exp.Body).Member;
        return (K)(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(info.DeclaringType)[info.Name]
            .Attributes.OfType<DefaultValueAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? default(K));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var deualtValue = someObject.GetDefaultValue(x=>x.SomeProperty);
```

**Note**

- The method tries to get the default value of the property based on the `DefaultValue` attribute, if there is no such attribute for the property, it returns the default value of the type of property, for example for an integer property, if it couldn't find `DefaultValue` attribute, it returns 0.
- To get attributes and metadata, I usually to use `TypeDescriptor` as it's more flexible, however using Reflection is also completely valid.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`GetCustomAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.8) method to get the desired attribute value. 
For example,
You could define the desired Extension method as

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetDefaultValue<S,T>(this S source,Expression<Func<S,T>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if(body.Member.GetCustomAttributes<DefaultValueAttribute>().Any())
        {
             return (T)body.Member.GetCustomAttribute<DefaultValueAttribute>().Value;
        }
        return default;
    }
}
```

In case, the desired attribute (in this case, `DefaultValueAttribute`) is not found, you could return the default value of the type (or throw exception depending on your usecase).

The usage would be as

```
string defaultNationality = employee.GetDefaultValue(x => x.employeeNationality);
```